# A hypothetical scenario regarding the pressure exerted by an ideal gas on the walls of a container using kinetic theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

This is a question I came across recently :

"1 mole of an ideal gas is contained in a cubical vessel of volume V, ABCDEFGH (these are the vertices of the cube). One of the faces of the cube EFGH is made up of a material which totally absorbs any gas molecules incident on it".

I was asked to determine the relation between the pressure on EFGH and any other face of the cube.

I was able to conclude that it will be half since it is evident from the derivation of the Kinetic Gas Equation and have gotten the right answer but am slightly intrigued by the situation.

Since EFGH is acting as an absorbent, any molecule that collides with that face will no longer be a part of the system. If you consider a large amount of time, you will reach a stage where there are barely any molecules so will the pressure on EFGH still be half of the pressure exerted on any other face?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Half seems like the correct answer here. You can visualize this using the fact that the impulse imparted on the other **reflecting** walls would be double the one imparted on the **absorbing** wall.

Since the wall absorbs the gas particles, the pressure on all the walls will decrease. However assuming that the motion of gas molecules is completely random, the pressure would still be half of the other walls.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with what you said but if you consider a hypothetical situation where there are no molecules left, this will be no longer be the case right? So I was having a problem understanding what they meant by absorb.

Comment: If there are no molecules left, the pressure is zero.  Half of zero is still zero, so the relationship isn't wrong, just unhelpful.

Comment: @DaveCoffman Just before the number of molecules is zero, this relation still holds.